# Increase count if time is within timestamp range

Tags: javascript

I have a map of times and counts as key, value pairs in 30 minute intervals over the last 24 hours that looks like this:

```
const value = new Map() // 1614789680148 => 0, 1614791480148 => 0, 1614793280148 => 0, 1614795080148 => 0,
```

I populate these values from another function. My problem now is that I am getting data from my api that has timestamp values and I need to check if the timestamp is within the intervals and add to the count (which are all 0 initially) if it is within the interval.

The array I get from the db looks like this (this is an example but there are over 500 elements in the array):

```
const arr = [
      {
        id: 2,
        details: {
          equipment: 31,
          payload: {
            createdTimestamp: 1614788205933
          }
        }
      }, 
      {
        id: 2,
        details: {
          equipment: 32,
          payload: {
            createdTimestamp: 1614788205937
          }
        }
      }, 
    ]
```

This is what I have right now but doesnt increment any values:

```
arr.forEach(i => {
      const currentTimestamp = fromTime;

      value.forEach(timestamp => {
        if (
          moment(i.details.payload.createdTimestamp).isBetween(
            currentTime,
            moment(currentTimestamp)
              .add('30', 'm')
              .valueOf()
          )
        ) {
          value.set(
            timestamp,
            value.get(timestamp) + 1
          );
        }
      });
    });
```

Edit.
This is how I set the intervals:

```
const fromTime = moment()
      .subtract(24, 'hours')
      .valueOf();
    const toTime = moment().valueOf();
    let currentTime = fromTime;

while (moment(currentTime).isBetween(fromTime, toTime, undefined, '[]')) {
        const thirtyMinutes = 30 * 60 * 1000;
        const key = Math.round(currentTime / thirtyMinutes) * thirtyMinutes;

        temp[i].value.set(key, 0);
currentTime = moment(currentTime)
          .add('30', 'm')
          .valueOf();
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, Map.forEach passes key and value. Value being the first argument, key being the second. You are assigning timestamp to the value, not the key.

Secondly, if I understand your goal correctly, it might be more efficient to round to the nearest 30 minute interval instead of doing all those comparisons:

```js
arr.forEach(i => {
    const thirtyMinutes = 30 * 60 * 1000;
    const key = Math.round(i.details.payload.createdTimestamp / thirtyMinutes) * thirtyMinutes;
    values.set(key,value.get(key) + 1);
});
```

Comment: The map is already set in my first code snippet with keys being timestamps of 30 minute intervals and values being the count. What my problem is that I get data from the api and I need to take the timestamp of the data objects and put it in the correct interval of the map by just increasing the count

Comment: Yep. My answer should address that. I'm saying round the createdTimestamp from the API, that way you don't have to iterate over your map to find a matching key.

Comment: That is a smart idea but the 30 minute intervals are calculated when Initialized and arent rounded. Is there a way to do this using the past 30 minute intervals in the past 24 hours to the second?

Comment: Or is there a way to set the intervals of value to fit this solution?

Comment: How are you generating the intervals? Are they sourced from something? Or are you just creating them based on the current time? You could do const t = moment().startOf('day'), and then for(i =0; i < 24 * 2; i++) values.set(t + i * 30,0);

Comment: I added an edit to the question if you want to check it out

Comment: I am also getting an error as I have 600 items in the array and only about 120 are being set to values @Kyle